# ANT - Conditional execution of macro within target

Tags: ant, macros

I'm attempting to implement what I believe should be pretty basic conditioning but am not having any success. I have a target (deploy.DEVELOPMENT) and within this target I call two macros that backup/restore an ini file we using for configuration. The outline is this:

```
<target name="deploy.DEVELOPMENT" description="Deploy to DEVELOPMENT">  
<echo>START: Deploy to ${mode.dev}</echo>
<echo>SOURCE: ${dir.source}</echo>
<macroBackupSourceConfigFile />
<macroUpdateConfigFile
keyDatasource="${setting.devdsn}"
keyServer="${server.devdevweb11}"
keyAppName="${setting.devappname}"
keyApplicationID="${setting.applicationid}"/>
<macroCopyFiles dirSource="${dir.source}" dirTarget="${dir.devdevweb11}"/>                                      
<macroRestoreSourceConfigFile />
<echo>END: Deploy to ${mode.dev}</echo>           
</target>
```

In certain projects an ini file is not required, therefore I would not need to run either of the two macros, just the macroCopyFiles would run. I'd like to just set a property at the top of my ant file to specify whether these macros should be executed.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Best Regards,

Gary

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need... It will perform a check. If file abc.txt is available, abc.present property will exist. Other target will call check-abc and check wether the property abc.present exists. If so, it will execute, else it will not.

```
<target name="check-abc">
    <available file="abc.txt" property="abc.present"/>
</target>

<target name="do-if-abc" depends="check-abc" if="abc.present">
    ...
</target>
```

Comment: Hey Pat, thanks for the reply. However I think I need something slightly different. I agree with your code and how it would or would not execute, but I need the target to always execute. It's just the calls to the two macros within the target that I need conditioning to handle.

Comment: @user2274650 Try to use the if and unless namespace attributes supported in more modern versions of ANT. Allows you to control execution of ANT tasks. See https://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html